# $PATH in Vim doesn't match Terminal

Tags: macos, vim, path, environment-variables, macvim

I'm using MacVim and when I don't launch it from the Terminal (`mvim`) its $PATH does not include what I have set in my .bash_profile. It only seems to have the default values, `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

I'm running OS X 10.5.8. Even if I could set it manually in my .vimrc that would be okay, though I would prefer it to pull from the same place as Terminal. I've tried following what one site suggested, adding `let $PATH += /blah/foo:/bar/etc` to no avail.

**Edit/Solution:** See my answer below. MacVim has an option to fix this.

Comment: Similar [question here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15739/9850)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) appears to be getting the $PATH in a way that ignores a regular user's custom dotfiles.

I can't say *why* they prefer to do it this way, but it appears to be true. In the preferences (under the Advanced tab), you can choose to "Launch Vim processes in a login shell", but it only improves the `$PATH` slightly for me.

The best I can tell, MacVim uses `/usr/libexec/path_helper` - which in turn uses the items found (1) in the `/etc/paths` file and (2) anything additional found in the `/etc/paths.d/` directory. Any changes made in a user's home directory (via `.profile` or the like) is ignored.

In a nutshell, you get the OSX defaults, plus any applications that add themselves to `/etc/paths.d`. (For example, MacTex does so on my system.) So if you want to adjust your MacVim path, one way would be to add a file with items to `/etc/paths.d`. (I wouldn't directly edit `/etc/paths` since then you run the risk of the changes being undone by system updates.)

Thanks for letting me know this. I'm off to file a wishlist bug at MacVim.

Comment: I would have thought that as well, but I have added a few things '/etc/paths.d/' which show up in Terminal but not with MacVim.

Comment: And actually, there's more in my '/etc/paths' file than what's in MacVim's path.

Comment: @Donut: well, that is odd. On my machine, if I add something to `/etc/paths.d`, it shows up the next time I boot MacVim. What format are you putting in there? It should be one item per line, I believe, with a $PATH directory on each line (e.g., /usr/texbin).

Comment: I totally missed your first paragraph originally: Choosing to "Launch Vim processes in a login shell" did the trick for me. See my answer.

Comment: Does anyone know if current MacVim (Vim 9.0.1276, MacVim r176 on my system) is supposed to Hhave with respect to paths/$PATH (as it's established in user's custom, shell dotfiles)?

Answer (score 9):

BTW, the "Launch Vim processes in a login shell" preference is no longer available in MacVim (at least not v7.3).  I see that launching MacVim from the Finder gets the wrong path, but launching it from a shell (as "mvim") gets the correct path.

Comment: You can add $PATH to ~/.zprofile and everything will work

Answer (score 3):

It's not sourced from .bash_profile, but you can use this in your .vimrc:

```
let $PATH=$PATH . ':/blah/foo'
```

You have to have the : or it won't be a correct PATH variable.

Comment: I just tried it, and this doesn't seem to change the $PATH for MacVim. I also tested it with Vim in the Terminal (both `/usr/bin/vim` (from Apple) and `/opt/local/bin/vim` (from MacPorts), and it seems unnecessary. Vim in the terminal already picks up the proper $PATH as sourced by my dot files.

Comment: I tried this as well to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe I didn't see this before. Okay, I can believe it. Anyways, MacVim comes with an option that solves this. Under Preferences just check "Launch Vim processes in a login shell". That's it, it works. Snazzy. Stupid me.

#### Oops

I accidentally wrote this answer not realizing that Telemachus had already given me the [correct answer](https://superuser.com/questions/31353/path-in-vim-doesnt-match-terminal/47166#47166). Marked his as the answer.

Comment: Glad it's sorted

Answer (score 2):

MacVim will source `~/.zprofile` and `/etc/profile`, so you can put your `PATH` settings in there.

See https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/Troubleshooting#for-zsh-users and [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344704/).

(Tested with MacVim version 7.3 (65)).

Answer (score 1):

[This Mac Dev Center article](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html) may be of some use.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Could be doing something wrong. The article suggests adding the 'LSEnvironment' property in an app's 'information property list file' which I assumed to be ~/Library/Preferences/org.vim.MacVim.plist. I made it a dictionary with 'PATH' (also tried 'path' and '$PATH') as the a key and what I want for the path as a string value. Still seems to be pulling PATH from some mysterious source. [Screenshot of the plist file](http://screencast.com/t/0B7vp3NwCv)

Answer (score 1):

I had no problem adding a file to the paths.d directory.  I added a file called mysql, whose contents were:

/usr/local/mysql/bin[Return]

Then I placed this file under the paths.d directory, and changed its ownership to root:wheel.  Now the mysql directory is automatically added to my $PATH variable.

I didn't investigate fully, but possibly (a) including the [RETURN] at the end of the line, and/or (b) setting the file ownership to root, might be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today. MacVim no longer has the "login shell" option, and editing system-wide files for a user-specific setting is sketchy.

Here's a solution using only vim options (see `:help :!` and `:help shell`).

In your `~/.vimrc` add the lines

```
set shell=/bin/bash
set shellcmdflag=-l\ -c
```

This makes `bash` your default shell from (Mac)Vim, and adds the `-l` flag (login shell) to commands invoked with `:!{cmd}`. When executing `:shell`, bash is started as an "interactive shell that is not a login shell".

To make the `$PATH` work, you need to have it set in `~/.bash_profile` for `:!`, and `~/.bashrc` for `:shell`. (See `INVOCATION` in `man bash`)

UPDATE: This wasn't necessary on my other computer, so there is likely something else that is the root cause.

Comment: You can do a similar thing for zsh. Define `$PATH` in `.zprofile`, and include the `-l` flag in either `set shell` or `set shellcmdflag`.

Answer (score 0):

I know more about unix than about macs, so the following advice may or may not work.
Try putting this your .vimrc file:

```
! source ~/.bash_profile
```

That might do the trick, but there's a slight caveat: the .bash_profile is only meant to be sourced once.  It may contain some non-idempotent commands (things which should only execute once).  Case in point:

```
$PATH += /blah/foo:/bar/etc
```

The more that gets called, the bigger and more redundant `$PATH` gets.  However, if that's not such a big deal, the recommendation on unix would be to put the one-time command in `~/.bashrc` and run `source ~/.bashrc` from your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: Neither sourcing .bash_profile or .bashrc worked. I tried manually running `:source .bash_profile` but it just comes up with a "Not an editor command" error for every command in the file and the same with .bashrc.

Comment: sorry...what was I thinking...you might try ! source .bash_profile

Comment: Tried both .bash_profile and .bashrc but still no go. Here's what I'm using in my .bash_profile to change PATH: 'PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Espresso.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Tools/:/Applications/MacVim/:$PATH' And in my .bashrc: 'export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin:$PATH'. And it's .bash_profile that actually affects my Terminal sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a very similar question [On the Vim StackExchange Site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15739/9850) and posted an answer there that works for me!